# Restoring a Database Using Full Backup Using Full Backup and Transactional Logs in SSMS

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, backup, restore

Hi I have a full backup file (.bak file) of a database for the 25/10/2019. However I want to restore the database to the 21/10/2019. My problem is that I do not have the full backup files for the 21/10/19. The last full backup for the database I have is 25/10/19. What I do have are transactional logs going back to the 21/10/19.

In SSMS I have tried using the full backup file for 25/10/2019 and using the preceding transactional log files to restore the database to 21/10/19 however it does not work and says unable to create restore plan due to break in LSN chain.

Please note a full backup of the database is made each night and every 30 minutes for the transactional logs.

The full backups prior to 25/10/2019 have been deleted.

Is it still possible to restore the database to a point in time using transactional logs?  Either within SSMS or command?

Comment: Please note there are no differential backups.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. For admin ones try dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sorry didn't know